# Search order of HttpRequest indexer

Tags: c#, asp.net, request, httprequest

If you do a simple index into Request's items via Request[key], it looks in [4 locations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx).  What's the order?  Someone makes a guess on that page at "Cookies, ServerVariables, Form and QueryString".  Does anyone know for sure?  Documentation would be a bonus :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> public string this[string key] { get; }
>
> Declaring Type: System.Web.HttpRequest  Assembly: System.Web,
>   Version=2.0.0.0

```
public string this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        string str = this.QueryString[key];
        if (str != null)
        {
            return str;
        }
        str = this.Form[key];
        if (str != null)
        {
            return str;
        }
        HttpCookie cookie = this.Cookies[key];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            return cookie.Value;
        }
        str = this.ServerVariables[key];
        if (str != null)
        {
            return str;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just another useful reference: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETParamsCollectionVsQueryStringFormsVsRequestindexAndDoubleDecoding.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and you can see it for yourself.  The order is QueryString, Form, Cookies, then ServerVariables.

Answer (score 1):

This is from an [ASP site](http://www.asp101.com/articles/pauld/request/default.asp), but it still applies to ASP.NET:

> All request object variables can be
>   accessed directly by calling
>   Request(variable) without the
>   collection name. In this case, the Web
>   server searches the collections in the
>   following order:
>
> 1. QueryString
> 2. Form
> 3. Cookies
> 4. ClientCertificate
> 5. ServerVariables

Comment: Reflector says that "ClientCertificate" isn't searched in .Net 2.0.